# Is my server missing a javascript component that it requires?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am trying to create a website that plays HTML5 video and displays SRT subtitles. I'm trying to emulate what is done [here](http://accessibility.oit.ncsu.edu/video/audiodescriptions/headingsmap-captions-only.html), but when I do the same thing on [my website](http://www.suchipi.com/stream/stream.html), FireBug reports `TypeError: textTrack[i] is undefined` in the javascript debugger. I'm running a Debian Squeeze server with apache2, php, etc. Are there any components I need to install to get javascript working properly? I tried editing the htmltexttrack.js that is powering the subtitles to hardcode a value for i, but it still reported errors that it wasn't defined, leading me to believe that some essential piece of javascript is missing.

Comment: JavaScript runs in your browser (with some exceptions, such as [tag:node.js]), not on the server. Have you tried [JS Hint](http://jshint.com/) for debugging?

Comment: JavaScript is usually run om the client, thus there shouldn't be any server dependencies causing this. It's all on the client.

Comment: Looking at both sites in the debugger, it's apparent that the same exception you think prevents your site from showing the subtitles also occurs on the original website. So forget that thought.

Comment: the `textTrack` array is empty. Can inspect it in DOM tab of Firebug, or log it to console. Either not implementing plugin properly or there is a bug in it...more likely implementation issue

Comment: I don't see any exception thrown on the original site, but for the sake of testing, I copied the original site's source and put it [here](http://www.suchipi.com/stream/sample.html), and it still does not work.

Comment: I see the video in the two websites is working just fine in Chrome

Comment: Neither website works for me in Chrome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code in firebug and for some reason, my browser can not access the caption file on it's original source within the `html5texttrack.js`(of curse I can access the file directly from my browser)

```
<track kind="caption" src="http://accessibility.oit.ncsu.edu/video/audiodescriptions/source/captions.vtt" label="English" />
```

firebug does not generate any errors but in the console log, there is a read line for the `GET` method requesting this file.

what I did, copied the caption file on my computer and then changed the line of code which loads the caption to this:

```
<track kind="caption" src="captions.vtt" label="English">
```

and everything worked like a charm...

Comment: This led me to believe that it might be a permissions issue, so I changed the video and subtitle to files on my server, and did a `chmod 770` to them, but the same error is still being thrown.

Comment: can you provide the link please?
cause in this [link](http://www.suchipi.com/stream/sample.html) the caption is still on the original server

Comment: It's [here](http://www.suchipi.com/stream/stream.html). Something that should be noted is that my /var/www/media is a symbolic link elsewhere on my server.

Comment: It's all related to the format of your caption file.  
the `eol`s should be `unix` formated, not `windows` formated.  
it means that end of lines only should have `\n` or `[LF]` but your caption files have `\r\n` or `[CR][LF]` in end of files.
also there should not be any extra blank line at the end of the file...
(These are the limitation of the `html5texttrack.js` file and you can find them by debugging)
So, either edit your caption file to meet the `html5texttrack.js` standards, or change `html5texttrack.js`.
you can easily edit you caption file using notepad++

Comment: I used Notepad++ and converted the EOLs to unix standard (using Edit -> EOL Conversion), but I am still experiencing the same issues. Also, thank you for your in-depth help with this! I hope we can figure it out.

Edit: I removed the trailing lines from the end of my SRT file and the errors are now not being thrown- however, I still see no subtitles, but I suspect that this may be misconfiguration of my styles.

Comment: no problems, I'm having fun :)  
I forgot to mention this one big problem with your caption file...  
If you compare your caption file with the original, you can see that in the original file the millisecond separators are `.` but in your file, they are `,`  
so change all the `,` for the millisecond separator to `.` and I think it will work fine...

Comment: That did it, it works perfectly now. Thanks! I'll have to make sure all my srt files are up to these standards.